# DVC Error: Failed to import 'filepath' because 'filepath' does not exist

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab, dvc

I'm trying to import my model from my repository A (ML repo which contains a model file) to my repository B (program repo which will use the model file). I have successfully added the model into repository A and pushed the actual model and its metadata to the remote storage and git (repo A) respectively. I've checked on gitlab and there is a file called models.dvc which means everything worked correctly.

However, when I try to import the model (models.dvc) from repository A to repository B by running:

```
git import git@gitlab.com:myusername/my-repository-A.git models
```

I receive this error and warning (note: some confidential data has been modified including the repository URL):

```
ERROR: failed to import 'models' from 'git@gitlab.com:myusername/my-repository-A.git'. - The path 'models' does not exist in the target repository 'git@gitlab.com:myusername/my-repository-A.git' neither as a DVC output nor as a Git-tracked file.: 
WARNING: Failed to remove 'C:\Users\USER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpcx29dmkbdvc-clone' - [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\USER~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpcx29dmkbdvc-clone\\.git\\objects\\pack\\pack-a7340dd2ea418c0c32d32c69adcdbf61ebec78c3.idx'
```

What could be the possible causes and how do I solve this? Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Does `dvc list git@gitlab.com:myusername/my-repository-A.git models` work for you?

Comment: Running `dvc list git@gitlab.com:myusername/my-repository-A.git models` returns `ERROR: unexpected error` but `dvc list git@gitlab.com:myusername/my-repository-A.git` (without "models") does return the list of files in the repository and `models.dvc` and `models` (folder) do exist in the list.

Comment: That's strange. Feel free to create an issue on https://github.com/iterative/dvc/issues and post full verbose logs so we could take a closer look.